# Adding security groups to distribution groups (exchange2010)

Tags: exchange-2010, distribution

I'm trying to add our current AD security groups as distribution lists. For example the i would like IT to get forwarded those that are members of the IT security groups. These are all nested under domain.local\users.

I have tried creating a distribution group and then making the account that was created a member of the security group and that doesnt seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit more fiddling and found the solution (i've been on this all day).

under AD you go to the security groups properties and change the group scope from "global" to "universal" it then allowed me to go into exchange 2010 and create a new distribution group using an existing name and pull it from the list.

I have added and tested all of our accounts and aside from it creating the email It2@domain.com (because there is already IT@domain.com) but that will be something I will research more into later.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you should be able to do is add an email address to the security group itself through AD. Are you on Windows Server 2008 or 2003?
Another more tedious method if you're planning on working exclusively through Exchange 2010 is to create a distribution group and manually add the members of the IT security group.

Comment: We use server 2008. I dont mind adding people through AD vs exchange itself as long as I can add these existing AD security groups to be email groups as well.

Comment: All the members of our company are already added to these security groups. this is why I am trying to add it this way. When we get a new employee I can create their accounts/add them to these security groups and they are then part of the distribution groups. Thanks for the speedy response!!

Comment: Ah I see, though going back to my original answer I still think that's the easiest route. Under your IT security group in AD, for example, once you set the email address it should automatically propagate as a "distribution" group as well (not in AD). In Exchange 2010 Management Console you should be able to see the newly created email as a distribution group under 'Recipient Configuration'. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: So currently under AD they are set as security groups. Because this is for domain/share access they will need to stay as security i'm guessing. So does this mean I need to create new distribution groups? or is there a way to tie into these? 

setting the email under the main page does not add them to exchange automatically. None of the security groups are part of the exchange emails. nor can I find a way to import them in =(